# TypeError: 'Keyword argument not understood:', 'padding'

Tags: python, keras

I am trying to implement the following python code, but I get the following error. Could anyone help me?

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.constraints import maxnorm
from keras.layers.convolutional import Convolution2D

# Create the model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Convolution2D(32, 3, 3, input_shape=(3, 32, 32), activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_constraint=maxnorm(3)))
```

The error I get:

> File "C:\Users\Lenovo\Anaconda2\envs\example_env\lib\site-packages\keras\layers\convolutional.py", line 388, in **init**
>       super(Convolution2D, self).**init**(**kwargs)
>
> File "C:\Users\Lenovo\Anaconda2\envs\example_env\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\topology.py", line 323, in **init**
>       raise TypeError('Keyword argument not understood:', kwarg)
>
> TypeError: ('Keyword argument not understood:', 'padding')

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You seem to be completely mixing Keras 2 API use with Keras 1, and you seem to have Keras 1 installed (as you are using Convolution2D).

In Keras 1, the parameter to control padding is not called `padding`, but `border_mode`.

But in any case, don't mix Keras 2 code with Keras 1, be careful about what documentation you read.

Answer (score 0):

As said by [Dr. Snoopy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/349130/matias-valdenegro), I too had the same error, when I was trying to use a model file generated by Keras 2.1.3 in Keras 2.0.4.

I solved it by upgrading Keras to latest version ([for more infor check here](https://machinelearningmastery.com/introduction-python-deep-learning-library-keras/))

> pip install --upgrade keras

To check your Keras version

```
import keras
print('keras: %s' % keras.__version__)
```